# knockout.js - broadcast data across relevant views

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am currently undertaking an exercise to research on a number of JS MV* frameworks and select one that best suits the team's needs. Knockout is one of the contenders that I am learning about.

One of the most important requirements is for changes in the data in a view model to be broadcast to all the views that use such data. For example, lets say we have client details listed in a data grid on a page, clicking on any row in the data grid brings up a pop-up dialog where the user can edit the values of the selected row. When the change is made and the user clicks 'Save', the data is updated in the database. But what we also want is that the change be reflected in the local ko.observablearray and then for any other views that use this 'clients' collection to refresh themselves with the new data. In other words the views must refresh themselves with the data in ko.observablearray rather than get a fresh list from the database.

I have been successful in doing this - have one a single .cshtml file which houses the data grid and a form to create new row in the data grid. In this scenario, the data in the grid refreshes correctly. But when the change happens on a another cshtml file, I am not able to carry these changes across to the other views. Can this be done in knockout and if yes, please point me to an example of how and where this has been done.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Event aggregator pattern. I have made one for SignalR

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Install usign nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

If you have no use for SignalR you can then extract the relevant parts from my lib, demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/jh8JV/